# How do I input Terminal commands when running a rails server?

Tags: macos, terminal, ruby

I just started using Rails a few days ago, and I'm having trouble with terminal commands. The textbook I am reading keeps telling me to run Terminal commands while having a Rails server running. This doesn't seem possible because the terminal just keeps outputting information about the server instead of prompting new commands, i.e. *rake test*. Is there a command I need to input to force the terminal to prompt my commands once I start the rails server?

Answer (score 3):

From my rather limited experience of using Rails, I would first start the rails server and then create a new tab within the terminal to run your commands. To create the tab you might have to use something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Istead of starting the rails server you can start the console with the command:

```
rails console
```